# Use select query inside the Insert query for the same table name

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to use a "select" query inside the "Insert" query, But the condition is i want to use the same table name for both "select" and "Insert" query.
For Example
`mysql> insert into sample_elements (name,position,ownerel) values ('Namespace1',
select id from sample_elements where name='Namespace1',0);`

Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change your insert to look like the following :

```
insert into sample_elements (name,position,ownerel) select 'Namespace1',id,0 from sample_elements where name='Namespace1';
```

Basically instead of using values only use the select statement and insert the harcoded values as columns

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it. You can use:

```
INSERT INTO table (..fields) SELECT ..fields.. FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know mysql but can you try the following ?

```
insert into sample_elements select name, id, 0 from sample_elements where name='Namespace1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure. I think this insert inside select for finding already exists or for what purpose.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

here is another format that will work, using the 'SET' construct.  I prefer this format for most of my SQL as the field names are paired with the values - makes maintenance much easier than field/value lists which depend totally on positioning.

```
INSERT INTO sample_elements SET
name = 'Namespace1',
position = (SELECT id FROM sample_elements WHERE name='Namespace1'),
ownere1 = 0;
```

Comment: -1 This solution does not work for MySQL, which the OP clearly is using. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14302701/998919

Comment: it DOES work on mySQL, that's where I used it.  Please clarify where/how it doesn't work, as I think you'll find its your implementation/version/driver that's the problem, not mySQL.  regards

Comment: I did specify already, check the answer I linked. Please state the version of the MySQL database that you tried it on at least.

Comment: the answer you linked to is NOT for the same scenario as both my answer and the OP. There is no relevance with the answer you've linked to. I was merely pointing out that there is a different syntax which allows you to pair fields with values. But as you've asked for proof, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html - or 5.6, or 5.7.  "SET" is a well-defined part of the syntax

Comment: Sorry but you don't seem to get what's wrong with your answer. You can't reference table x in a sub query inside a query to table x, without a trick or two (as explained in the answer I linked). My -1 will remain, I'll leave it up to a third person to decide whether you're correct or not, whenever such a person comes along.