# Insert and set value with max()+1 problems

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, mysql-error-1093

I am trying to insert a new row and set the customer_id with max()+1. The reason for this is the table already has a auto_increatment on another column named id and the table will have multiple rows with the same customer_id.

With this:

```
INSERT INTO customers
  ( customer_id, firstname, surname )
VALUES 
  ((SELECT MAX( customer_id ) FROM customers) +1, 'jim', 'sock')
```

...I keep getting the following error:

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'customers' for update in FROM clause
```

Also how would I stop 2 different customers being added at the same time and not having the same customer_id?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Correct, you can not modify and select from the same table in the same query.  You would have to perform the above in two separate queries.

The best way is to use a transaction but if your not using innodb tables then next best is [locking the tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) and then performing your queries.  So:

```
Lock tables customers write;

$max = SELECT MAX( customer_id ) FROM customers;
```

Grab the max id and then perform the insert

```
INSERT INTO customers( customer_id, firstname, surname )
VALUES ($max+1 , 'jim', 'sock')

unlock tables;
```

Comment: @RDL - I am using MyISAM so your example will work correctly and allow 2 customers to be added at the same time with different customer id's? Thanks

Comment: @Cozzy, Correct.  When the table is locked only the current session has access to it.  All other requests for that table are placed in a queue until the table is unlocked.  Therefore no duplicates will happen from records being added at the same time.

Comment: Without a unique key on the customer_id column to validate, there is no guarantee that duplicate values can exist.  Additionally, the same max value can be read for the insert statements due to isolation level handling.  Why you wouldn't use the native AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: @RDL - I get the following error from the 1st query #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@max = SELECT MAX( customer_id ) FROM customers' at line 1

Comment: @Cozzy: Did you DECLARE the @max variable?  Why you want this approach baffles the mind.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - The reason is for the table will hold rows that is the old data before and after modifications. So you can actually see who and what has changed. Baffles my mind to! Might as well make a seperate table for this and just move the data from one table to another before deleting. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Cozzy: I fear for your data model, if you think this is the way to go for an audit table.

Comment: Locking the table is an heavy process... What if I have a `WHERE` in the `MAX` query? Turning `INSERT INTO x (id_autoincremented, num, channel) VALUES (DEFAULT, IFNULL((SELECT MAX(num) FROM x WHERE channel = ?), 0)+1, ?)` to `INSERT INTO x (num, channel) (SELECT IFNULL((SELECT MAX(num) FROM x WHERE channel = ?), 0)+1, ?)` won't lock the table and let other `INSERT` be done for other `channel`, so that's concurrent-safe?

Comment: I don't know why this answer is accepted. The [other answer with more upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5360154/8418610) is correct, succinct and disproves the statement "you can not modify and select from the same table in the same query".

Answer (score 115):

You can use the [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) statement to get the `MAX()+1` value and insert at the same time:

```
INSERT INTO 
customers( customer_id, firstname, surname )
SELECT MAX( customer_id ) + 1, 'jim', 'sock' FROM customers;
```

<sup>**Note:** You need to drop the `VALUES` from your `INSERT` and make sure the `SELECT` selected fields match the `INSERT` declared fields.</sup>

Comment: It may lead to race conditions it these queries are run exactly at the same time. You have to `lock table` before that.

Comment: @xmedeko I thought 1 query was always atomic, so since there is only 1 `INSERT` here, then it's an atomic operation and race-safe?

Comment: Nope, at least no for mysql. This query does select and then insert. They are not atomic. There is a slight chance of race condition.

Comment: Today I learned something new. I thought when performing everything in one query, duplicated queries were impossible, but look, I was wrong. Time to rewrite some things to avoid potential issues in the future.

Comment: I have a similar scenario that I may open a separate SO question for; Selecting the max() is the approach I was looking for too but after reading the comments above, I'm questioning myself. In my instance, I have a `WHERE` clause which is limiting my returned results to a specific subset so I _THINK_ I'm relatively safe from race conditions... right?

Comment: Does this still work in 2024? Was having a strange issue where after a MySQL update the SELECT MAX query has started returning NULL (even though it should be 120)

Answer (score 18):

Use alias name for the inner query like this

```
INSERT INTO customers
  ( customer_id, firstname, surname )
VALUES 
  ((SELECT MAX( customer_id )+1 FROM customers cust), 'sharath', 'rock')
```

Comment: @xmedeko This isn't a duplicate at all. EmCos answer demonstrates replacing VALUES() with SELECT, whereas this answer demonstrates how to nest  SELECT statement inside of VALUES() (which folks reading EmCos answer could think is impossible due to his "Note")

Comment: @Wipqozn you are right, it's not duplicate, but should be mentioned in the answer what's different. Also, my comments about race conditions apply to this answer, too.

Answer (score 6):

`SELECT MAX(col) +1` is not safe -- it does not ensure that you aren't inserting more than one customer with the same `customer_id` value, regardless if selecting from the same table or any others.  The [proper way to ensure a unique integer value is assigned on insertion into your table in MySQL is to use AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).  The ANSI standard is to use sequences, but MySQL doesn't support them.  An AUTO_INCREMENT column can only be defined in the CREATE TABLE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)
)
```

That said, this worked fine for me on 5.1.49:

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `firstname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$

INSERT INTO customers VALUES (1, 'a', 'b');

INSERT INTO customers 
SELECT MAX(customer_id) + 1, 'jim', 'sock'
  FROM CUSTOMERS;
```

Comment: How does that not ensure you aren't selecting more than one row? Unless there's a `group by`, then I cannot think of a situation where a query with `max()` will return multiple rows

Comment: He is not talking about retrieving more than one row with a max(), he is correctly pointing out that by using max(customer_id) + 1 to insert a new customer, you cannot be sure about that id's uniqueness. Two such statements executed at the same time, would result in two different customers having the same customer_id.

Comment: Using auto_increment would be a great solution ... if MySQL let you get the auto_increment value in a BEFORE INSERT trigger.  But it doesn't.  This is exactly why I'm here -- to find a way to re-implement built-in functionality inside a trigger that refuses to read from a table it's about to modify.  Seems like something I shouldn't have to do, but I haven't found a proper way to do it otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

Use table alias in subquery:

```
INSERT INTO customers
  ( customer_id, firstname, surname )
VALUES 
  ((SELECT MAX( customer_id ) FROM customers C) +1, 'jim', 'sock')
```

Comment: I think that would be:
    `INSERT INTO customers ( customer_id, firstname, surname )`
    `VALUES ((SELECT MAX( C.customer_id )`
    `FROM customers C) +1, 'jim', 'sock')`
But the following works on my install [mySQL ver 5.5.41]: 
    `INSERT INTO table1(id1) SELECT (max(id1)+1) FROM table1;`

Answer (score 5):

```
insert into table1(id1) select (max(id1)+1) from table1;
```

Comment: Does not work for MySQL, it does not allow the same table in INSERT and SELECT subquery.

Comment: Worked for me mySQL ver 5.5.41

Answer (score 4):

None of the about answers works for my case. I got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause), and my SQL is:

```
INSERT INTO product (id, catalog_id, status_id, name, measure_unit_id, description, create_time)
VALUES (
  (SELECT id FROM (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id),0)+1 AS id FROM product) AS temp),
  (SELECT id FROM product_catalog WHERE name="AppSys1"),
  (SELECT id FROM product_status WHERE name ="active"),
  "prod_name_x",
  (SELECT id FROM measure_unit WHERE name ="unit"),
  "prod_description_y",
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your sub-query is just incomplete, that's all. See the query below with my additions:

```
INSERT INTO customers ( customer_id, firstname, surname ) 
VALUES ((SELECT MAX( customer_id ) FROM customers) +1), 'jim', 'sock')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in a single query, but you could do it within a transaction. Do the initial MAX() select and lock the table, then do the insert. The transaction ensures that nothing will interrupt the two queries, and the lock ensures that nothing else can try doing the same thing elsewhere at the same time.

Comment: Please could you provide a example sql query? When using transaction and lock will it throw any errors if 2 customers are added at the same time or in a nutshell will it just queue them and run one after the other? Thanks

Comment: Actually, you can do the operation in a single statement -- no need for a transaction.  And SELECT MAX does not ensure unique values will always be returned -- reading queries are given preference over update queries in default isolation levels on pretty much every database.

Comment: Just a transaction is not enough, you have to lock table first.

Answer (score 0):

We declare a variable 'a'

```
SET **@a** = (SELECT MAX( customer_id ) FROM customers) +1;

INSERT INTO customers
  ( customer_id, firstname, surname )
VALUES 
  (**@a**, 'jim', 'sock')
```

Comment: you should probably add some more annotation to your code. Does this answer both questions asked? Why?

Answer (score 0):

This is select come insert sequel.

I am trying to get serial_no maximum +1 value and its giving correct value.

```
SELECT MAX(serial_no)+1 into @var FROM sample.kettle;
Insert into kettle(serial_no,name,age,salary) values (@var,'aaa',23,2000);
```