# Increment an ID within an INSERT INTO statement in AS400

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, insert-into

Is there a way to insert a new record to a table that has an non-unique id and set this id to the next number in the same SQL statement?

Something like

```
INSERT INTO T1 (id, fname, lname)
VALUES ([last id + 1], 'Dan', 'Thomson');
```

Comment: Use a WHILE loop with a counter variable?

Comment: @Alrightythen, it is not clear, can you please explain

Comment: posted a sample as an answer below.

Comment: This is not normal, your table should have a real id (primary key), the best is to add a column autoincremented. Of course you can also keep your old id if necessary. But use it as id is a bad idea because so many people add a line at the same time they will have potentially made the same id.

Comment: Of course you are right, I just put an example of what I need. ID is not really the field I am using for this concern. This may be a bad example. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this probably works

```
INSERT INTO T1 (id, fname, lname)
VALUES (ifnull((select max(id) from T1),0) + 1, 'Dan', 'Thomson')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @COUNTER INT;
SET @COUNTER = 1;

WHILE(@COUNTER <= XXX)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO T1 (id, fname, lname)
VALUES (@COUNTER, @FNAME , @LNAME);

SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Built-in function MAX](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzcolmax.htm?view=kc) :**

```
INSERT INTO T1 (id, fname, lname)
SELECT ifnull(MAX(id)+ 1,1), 'Dan', 'Thomson' FROM T1
```

> [Insert and set value with max()+1 problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360117/insert-and-set-value-with-max1-problems/5360198#5360198)
>
> SELECT MAX(col) +1 is not safe -- it does not ensure that you aren't inserting more than one customer with the same customer_id value, regardless if selecting from the same table or any others.

**For performance, add an index:**

```
CREATE INDEX T1_INDEX1 ON T1 (id) DESC
```

**References:**

- [MAX()](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzcolmax.htm?view=kc)
- [CREATE INDEX](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzxcindx.htm)
- [Index Advisor, Show Statements](https://www.ibm.com/partnerworld/wps/servlet/RedirectServlet?cmsId=stg_ast_sys_wp_db2_i_indexing_methods_strategies&attachmentName=ibm_db2_for_i_indexing_methods_and_strategies.pdf)
- [Accelerated analytics - faster aggregations using the IBM DB2 for i encoded vector index (EVI) technology](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-accelerated-analytics-db2-evi-tech/#_References:)

**Unit Test**

```
-- Create Table
SET SCHEMA QTEMP;
CREAT TABLE testtbl (
    id integer not null default,
    fname char(10) not null default,
    lname char(10) not null default)
;
-- Initialize Table with Data
insert into 
testtbl ( id , fname, lname)
values
( 1, 'fname1', 'lname_1'),
( 2, 'fname2', 'lname_2'),
( 2, 'fname3', 'lname_3'),
( 3, 'fname4', 'lname_4')
;
-- Test Insert Statement
INSERT INTO 
testtbl ( id, fname, lname )
SELECT ifnull(MAX( id ) + 1, 1), 'Dan', 'Thomson' FROM testtbl;
--Confirm Expectation
select * from testtbl;

ID           FNAME       LNAME       
-------------------------------------
1            fname1      lname_1     
2            fname2      lname_2     
3            fname4      lname_4     
4            Dan         Thomson
```

Comment: @ehh My bad. Answer Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

if you want insert all content of table with unique id start with max +1

```
INSERT INTO T1 (id, fname, lname)
select
rownumber() over() + ifnull((select max(T1.id) from T1), 0),
T2.zone1, T2.zone2 
from T2
```