# Get largest value from mySQL table and increase by one

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking to add a function that will get the largest number from a specific column in a table and add to it before doing an INSERT query. (I cant have it be auto increment as several entries need to have the same value this is controlled through an if statement) however it isnt doing this and isn't increasing it by 1 based off the highest value.

```
$max = "SELECT MAX(LocationID) FROM boss";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $max);
$locID = $result+1;

$query = "INSERT INTO boss (ID, Name, Type, Location, LocationID, Difficulty) VALUES ('0', '$boss', '$type', '$loc', '$locID', '$diff')";
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: And... you forgot to glance at a MySQL tutorial or example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert and set value with max()+1 problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360117/insert-and-set-value-with-max1-problems)

Comment: I need to only add 1 to the max if it doesn't comply into one of the other if statements.

Comment: Nobody ever needs to do this :-(

Comment: Why don't you just use `AUTO_INCREMENT` for this? Isn't that what you're already doing with the `ID` field, why do you need another field that increments?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use two queries for this, you can do it in the `INSERT` query.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO boss (ID, Name, Type, Location, LocationID, Difficulty)
    SELECT '0', '$boss', '$type', '$loc', MAX(locationID)+1, '$diff'
    FROM boss";
```

Comment: It's still a terrible idea. :-(

Comment: @Strawberry Agreed, it seems like he should just be able to use an auto increment column for this.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to fetch the result

```
$max = "SELECT MAX(LocationID) as m FROM boss";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $max);
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$locID = $result[0]+1;
```