# MS SQL Server UPDATE statement with JOIN in Spring and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two classes:

```
Course {
  ...
  private List<Student> students;
  private String var1;
  ...
}

Student {
  private Long id;
  ...
}
```

In my code, I was able to generate the following query dynamically and get results successfully:

```
SELECT c.var1 FROM Course c, IN (c.students) s WHERE s.id = :sid
```

Now I would like to do a update with the following dynamically generated query:

```
UPDATE c SET c.var1 = 'newvalue' FROM Course c, IN (c.students) s WHERE s.id = :sid
```

For this, I always got error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: node to traverse cannot be null!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
```

The reason I came up with the above UPDATE query is because I read this SO post:

[How can I do an UPDATE statement with JOIN in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql)

Here is my code:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("UPDATE c SET c.var1 = 'newvalue' FROM Course c, IN (c.students) s WHERE s.id = :sid");
query.setParameter("sid", 10);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: you cannot add FROM clauses in JPQL UPDATE statements, as any docs would show you. http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/jpql.html#JPQL_UPDATE_Queries

Comment: Neil, thanks sooooo much for chiming in. Based on your input, I found another post at SO that solved my problem. Basically, I need to use a subquery. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201895/update-value-with-join

Answer (score 1):

Based on the info from Nei Stockton, I did further search and found another post at SO that solved my problem.

[Update value with join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201895/update-value-with-join)

Basically, I need to use a subquery similar to the following given in the above post:

```
UPDATE Team t SET t.current = :current WHERE t.id in 
(select t1.id from Team t1  LEFT JOIN t1.members m WHERE t1.current = :current_true AND m.account = :account)
```

Cheers!