# MySQL UPDATE query where id is highest AND field is equal to variable

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to construct a MySQL query that will UPDATE a row in my table WHERE the id is highest AND a field called idSession is equal to 65. It looks like this:

```
UPDATE `History` 
SET `state` = 0 
WHERE `id` = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `History` WHERE `idSession` = 65);
```

And I'm getting the error message:

> "Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'History' for update
>   in FROM clause".

Anyone know what's wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944165/mysql-update-with-where-select-subquery-error

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Exactly what it says: You can't select from a table when you're updating that same table based on a condition from the exact same table. (That's intentionally confusingly written :p)

Try this:

```
UPDATE `History` SET `state`=0 WHERE `idSession`=65 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

You can use `ORDER` and `LIMIT` in `UPDATE` and `DELETE` queries ;)

Comment: Did not know you could use ORDER and LIMIT in UPDATE and DELETE queries. I constructed my query from this one, which works: 
SELECT `test1` FROM `History` WHERE `id` = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM `History` WHERE test2 = 'var1' AND test3 = 'var2');

Comment: Intelligent answer :)

Answer (score 7):

What about this:

```
UPDATE `History`
SET `state` = 0
WHERE `idSession` = 65
ORDER BY `id` DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a MySQL imitation. There are two ways around this (actually three but I don't like the 3rd one).

1) Because the query:

```
SELECT MAX(id) 
FROM History 
WHERE idSession = 65
```

produces same results as the:

```
SELECT id 
FROM History 
WHERE idSession = 65
ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

you can use the solution provided by @xdazz and @Kolink, changing the update to use the (proprietary MySQL) syntax of `ORDER BY` in the `UPDATE` statement.

2) The second way around this to join your table with the above subquery. This works in more complex conditions/subqueries/joins, that cannot be rewritten with a simple Order By:

```
UPDATE 
      History AS h
  JOIN
      ( SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id 
        FROM History 
        WHERE idSession = 65
      ) AS m
    ON m.max_id = h.id
SET h.state = 0 ;
```