# Syntax for UPDATE with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

How do you insert this query with an update? I've tried all possible combinations and nothing seems to work!

```
UPDATE Test_table2
SET Pledge_Status = closed
WHERE (
    SELECT SUM(pledgers.Pledge_payment_amt) AS pledged
    FROM Test_table2  AS recipients
    LEFT JOIN Test_table2 AS pledgers
    ON recipients.GIFT_NO = pledgers.PLEDGE_GIFT_NO
    GROUP BY recipients.GIFT_NO
    HAVING recipients.Pledge_Amt >= pledged
    ORDER BY recipients.CRSID ASC
);
```

Schema (all varchar):

> ID, Name, Pledge_Amount , Pledge_payment_amt , Gift_No, Pledge_Gift_No, Pledge_Open/Closed

Thank you so very much!

Comment: Please try to provide the table schema at least, this makes understanding your question a lot easier. And if you want to go the extra mile, take the time to create an example on http://sqlfiddle.com/.

Comment: sqlfiddle is awesome. Thanks http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aecf2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parallel to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944165/mysql-update-with-where-select-subquery-error) I suggest that you use `WHERE ... IN SELECT`. Also, you need to pass the ID of each row from the subselect to the main query, and since you didn't provide a table schema, we can only guess here:

```
UPDATE Test_table2
SET Pledge_Status = closed
WHERE [your id column] IN (
    SELECT [your id column]
    FROM Test_table2  AS recipients
    LEFT JOIN Test_table2 AS pledgers
    ON recipients.GIFT_NO = pledgers.PLEDGE_GIFT_NO
    GROUP BY recipients.GIFT_NO
    HAVING recipients.Pledge_Amt >= SUM(pledgers.Pledge_payment_amt)
    /*ORDER BY recipients.CRSID ASC <-- no need to order anything here */
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I decided to change play with my query and I wrote this: UPDATE Test_table2
set Pledge_Status = closed
where Test_table2.GIFT_NO  in 
(
select GIFT_NO FROM
 (
 SELECT recipients.*,SUM(pledgers.Pledge_payment_amt) AS pledged
 FROM Test_table2 AS recipients
 LEFT JOIN Test_table2 AS pledgers 
 ON recipients.GIFT_NO = pledgers.PLEDGE_GIFT_NO 
 GROUP BY recipients.GIFT_NO 
 HAVING recipients.Pledge_Amt >= pledged
 )
);

Why is this wrong?

Comment: `select GIFT_NO FROM (SELECT...` - You can't put a sub-SELECT in place of the table name. Also, the error message you get from the Database should explain most of your problems.