# Sql statement error basic

Tags: mysql, sql

Still getting to grips with sql but this seams like a pretty basic problem im obviously missing something big

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE arbitraryInt < (SELECT MAX(arbitraryInt));
```

I get no rows returned when i know for a fact that there are arbitraryInt values that are less than the max. Theres no error though just nothing returned. Thanks in advance

update: this is the rest of the code which still gets an error with FROM keyword

```
UPDATE myTable SET arbitraryInt = arbitraryInt + 1 
WHERE primaryKey = 0001 AND arbitraryInt < (
    SELECT MAX(arbitraryInt) FROM myTable
);
```

I get the error myTable is soecified twice

The context is im trying to make items manually sortable using a sorting integer for each item. So the reason for MAX is to keep that integer from getting bigger than necessary. I'm sure theres a bette way to do this but i havent seen it. The result im looking for is a table with up and down arrows to re order list items for an online store.

Comment: It seems odd to me that you can update a selected cursor. That might be your problem.

Comment: By sorting like that you'll end up incrementing some `arbitraryInt` value so that it matches `MAX(arbitraryInt)` and eventually they will all equal that `MAX()`.  I think you should allow the integer value to get bigger.  An integer will give you over 2 billion numbers.

Answer (score 0):

A subquery must be a complete query, capable of being run on its own. Your subquery

```
(SELECT MAX(arbitraryInt))
```

is not complete, as it does not specify a **`FROM`** clause. Your complete query should probably be something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM myTable
  WHERE arbitraryInt < (SELECT MAX(arbitraryInt)
                          FROM myTable);
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed this part of the query.. In context i now have   UPDATE myTable SET arbitraryInt = arbitraryInt + 1  WHERE primaryKey = 0001 AND arbitraryInt < (SELECT MAX(arbitraryInt) FROM myTable);    I get the error myTable is soecified twice

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `from` clause, so presumably you intend:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE arbitraryInt < (SELECT MAX(arbitraryInt) FROM mytable);
```

Answer (score 0):

This has feature in stack overflow before. Have a look at [MYSQL update with WHERE SELECT subquery error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944165/mysql-update-with-where-select-subquery-error)

```
The following code seems to be something like what you are asking for
/*
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (PRIMARYKEY INT, ARBITRARYID INT, AB1 INt)
*/

truncate table MYTABLE;
INSERT INTO MYTABLE
VALUES (1,1,NULL),(1,2,NULL),(1,3,NULL);

update  MYTABLE 
set     ARBITRARYID = ARBITRARYID + 1
where   PRIMARYKEY = 1 and
        ARBITRARYID <=  (
        SELECT MAXABID FROM
        (
        select max(ARBITRARYID) MAXABID FROM MYTABLE
        ) S
        )
;
select * from MYTABLE
```