# Use SELECT result to query another table's row

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a pretty simple MySQL query to implement, but I can't figure out how...

I have two tables, **T1** and **T2**.

#### What I need to do:

From **T1**, I retrieve an *ID* based on a *CODE* value:

```
SELECT id FROM T1 WHERE code = '$code';
```

Then I need to use this *ID* (so the value I just retrieved) to update a specific row in **T2** (the name of the row will match the *ID*'s value).

I was thinking about using either subqueries or user-defined variables, but no matter how I try it I can't get it done.

If you have any code snippet that can help me doing that, I would appreciate it as well!

#### EDIT

Just to clarify something: I don't know the name of the column that I need to update in **T2**, since that name will be the value I retrieve from **T1**.

So for example, if the *ID* I get from **T1** is "*03*", it will update the column named "*03*" in **T2**.

#### EDIT 2

Here's a little schema of what I intend to achieve (hoping I make myself clearer, I'm sorry for the misunderstanding...)

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL update with WHERE SELECT subquery error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944165/mysql-update-with-where-select-subquery-error)

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE T2 SET COL = YOUR_VALUE
WHERE T2.ID = (SELECT id FROM T1 WHERE code = '$code')
```

**UPDATE**: If the sub query returns more than one row then you can use from `IN` operator

```
UPDATE T2 SET COL = YOUR_VALUE
WHERE T2.ID IN (SELECT id FROM T1 WHERE code = '$code')
```

Comment: this only works if `SELECT id FROM T1 WHERE code = '$code'` returns only one row.

Comment: Yes that is the case.

Answer (score 4):

Use an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE T2
CROSS JOIN T1
SET T2.`0` = IF(T1.id = 0, T1.someColumn, T2.`0`),
    T2.`1` = IF(T1.id = 1, T1.someColumn, T2.`1`),
    T2.`2` = IF(T1.id = 1, T1.someColumn, T2.`1`)
WHERE T1.code = '$code'
```

Replace `someColumn` with the column in `T1` containing the value you want to put into `T2`.

Comment: you also need to have `JOIN T1 ON T2.name = T1.id AND code = '$code'` or a `WHERE code = '$code'` here

Comment: What are "name" and "column" in this example? Are they MySQL keywords or should they be part of my tables?

Comment: You wrote "the name of the row will match the ID's value". So `name` is the column that matches the ID's value. And `column` is the column you want to update in the rows that match

Comment: Yes I think that wasn't very clear. The thing is I don't know the name of the column since that name will be defined by the ID that I get from the first table. I updated my question to explain it better.

Comment: Could you update the question to show sample data in the two tables and what the result of the update should be?

Comment: This is becoming very unclear. Isn't `T1.id` the column being used to join the two tables? How can it also be used to determine which column should be updated?

Comment: Ok I just edited my question, tell me if it's still unclear. :)

Comment: What is the final result supposed to look like? How do you determine which row in T2 to update?

Comment: I've updated the answer with my latest guess at what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

you can update without using the subquery just using join

```
  update t2
  inner join t1 on t2.name = t1.id and t1.code ='$code'
  set t2.my_col = 'my_value'
```

but you should not use  var in your query  you are at risk for sql injection  take a look at you mysql driver for param_binding

Comment: @RaymondNijland  . .. Thanks  .. answer  updated  avoiding t2.id  ..but a generic column

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE T2 SET COL = YOUR_VALUE WHERE EXISTS 
 (SELECT 1 FROM T1 WHERE T2.id=T2.id AND code = '$code')
```

Comment: Please provide some information as to how the code above answers the question in order to improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can update T2 with the next SQL if you expect at least one row from the inner query

```
UPDATE T2 SET COLUMN = VALUE 
WHERE T2.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM T1 WHERE CODE = $code)
```

Otherwise, if from T1 you are sure you will get only 1 record

```
UPDATE T2 SET COLUMN = VALUE 
WHERE T2.ID = (SELECT ID FROM T1 WHERE CODE = $code)
```