# SQL Server : Update WHERE xxx AND most recent record

Tags: sql-server

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505859/sql-update-where-xx-and-most-recent-record), but I require this in Microsoft SQL Server.

I'm looking to update values in my database, but only the most recently added value for each date.

For example if I have 4 rows where `column_day = '2023-02-01'`,
and they have updated datetimes in a column `[Time_Stamp]` of
`2023-01-01`, `2023-01-27`, `2023-01-10`, and `2023-01-05`,
I would like to only update the Jan 27, 2023 `2023-01-27` line.

The [answer provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14505882/1393894) which does not work in Microsoft SQL Server is:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET some_column = 1
ORDER BY date_time_column DESC
LIMIT 1
```

My code I'm trying is slightly different as it includes a `WHERE`:
I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'

```
UPDATE your_table
SET some_column = 1
WHERE column_tag = 'test' AND column_day = '2023-02-01'
ORDER BY Time_Stamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

How can I achieve this in Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TOP` in an `UPDATE`, however, you *can't* provide an `ORDER BY`; as such it's really used for batching and previously `UPDATE`d rows are filtered in each iteration in the `WHERE` clause.

For what you want, one method would be to use an `UPDATE`able CTE with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT SomeColumn,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date_time_column DESC) AS RN
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    WHERE ColumnTag = 'Test'
      AND ColumnDay = '20230201')
UPDATE CTE
SET SomeColumn = 1
WHERE RN = 1;
```