# Update mysql table where select from same table

Tags: mysql

I am new to MYSQL query statements and i am currently stuck at some piece of code as following

```
UPDATE fb_messages
SET sent = 'Yes' 
WHERE msg_id = (SELECT MAX(msg_id) AS MSG_ID 
                FROM fb_messages
                WHERE sent = 'No')
```

I am getting this error

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'fb_messages' for update in FROM clause
```

I searched for a solution to work around for similar cases but i really couldn't find, please help

Comment: @Amandeep Jiddewar It seems so but unfortunately when i put it in my SQL section and hit Go the above error appears to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
   UPDATE fb_messages
   SET sent = 'Yes'
   WHERE sent = 'No'
   ORDER BY msg_id DESC
   limit 1
```

Comment: Thank you @echo_me your second option worked for me like a charm

Comment: @user2151383 Nice that it helped you!. make sure to accept the answer as solved.good luck

Answer (score 7):

This should work.

```
UPDATE fb_messages fb1, (SELECT MAX(msg_id) AS MSG_ID 
                FROM fb_messages
                WHERE sent = 'No') fb2
SET sent = 'Yes' 
WHERE fb1.msg_id = fb2.MSG_ID
```

**Note** : This will create a temporary, and if there are large number of rows then query gets slow, try to create an temporary table with index/primary key [Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-select.html) (Source : Alex [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause/4429409#comment20742824_4429409))

see this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c79c)

Answer (score 0):

"In MySQL, you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part.
This behaviour is documented at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html"

Break it up into two statements.

```
CREATE TABLE Updates (
  msg_id int
);

INSERT Updates (msg_id)
SELECT
  MAX(msg_id)
FROM fb_messages
WHERE sent = 'No';

UPDATE fb_messages o, Updates u
SET o.sent = 'Yes'
WHERE o.msg_id = u.msg_id
```

There's a workaround covered in the article below

Reference: [MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Answer (score -1):

Please add one more select query in between `WHERE` condition

Example:

```
UPDATE t1 
SET t1.Status = 5
WHERE t1.SearchID NOT IN 
(SELECT TMP.SearchID FROM 
    (SELECT MIN(t1.SearchID) AS SearchID
  FROM t1 
 WHERE t1.ID = '750') TMP)
 AND t1.ID = '750'
```