# Mysql pdate query error

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

I am  trying to update my `mysql` table "upproj" using `Visual Studio 2010` (`c#`).
I want to execute the following query :

```
string Query = " update tlog.upproj set summ=(select sum(grade) from tlog.upproj group by ams having count(*) =2); ";
```

But I get error

```
"You can't specify target table 'upproj' for update in FROM clause".
```

When I execute the previous query on `Mysql` Query browser I don't get any error, but my project  needs to execute this query from visual studio.

Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of your `UPDATE` query? If that *were* to work, it would update every row in the table as there is no `WHERE` clause set on it.

Comment: And see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14302701/1385896) on a similar question.

Comment: The purpose of update is to set values to summ column. I do this though visual studio cause ,instead of '2' in having count subquery, i use a variable that is given on vs project. And sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error hints at, you can't specify the table you're updating in the `UPDATE` statement's `FROM` clause (in the sub-query); the same is true if you were to try to use it in a `WHERE` clause.

You can accomplish the task of "using the table you're updating" if you use a `JOIN` though.

Based on the schema inferred by your existing query, the `ams` field is unique to a set grouping and you can, therefore, add that as part of your clause.

Try the following (untested):

```
UPDATE
    tlog.upproj AS u1
    JOIN (SELECT ams, SUM(grade) AS grade_sum FROM tlog.upproj GROUP BY ams HAVING COUNT(*) = 2) AS u2
        ON u1.ams = u2.ams
SET
    summ = u2.grade_sum;
```

This should update each record for `ams` with the total sum of `grade` for that same `ams`. If a specific `ams` doesn't have 2 entries, it isn't updated.