# How to use data in same table on UPDATE query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
update accounts set password=(select password from accounts where name='joongsu') 
where id=(select accountid from characters where name='Nobless')
```

it doesn't work with error message "You can't specify target table 'accounts' for update in FROM clause"

Why doesn't it work? select queries in above only return 1 row.

Comment: You query says UPDATE... password=password WHERE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14302701/3416826):

```
UPDATE accounts
SET accounts.password =
(
    SELECT something.password
    FROM (SELECT * FROM accounts) AS something
    WHERE something.name='joongsu'
)
WHERE accounts.id=(SELECT accountid FROM characters WHERE name='Nobless');
```

It's a hack, but I tested it and it works on my test data. For some reason MySQL doesn't allow  using the same table in inner queries as the one being updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE
    accounts AS account_to_be_updated
  JOIN 
    characters
      ON  characters.accountid = account_to_be_updated.id
      AND characters.name = 'Nobless'
  CROSS JOIN
    ( SELECT password
      FROM   accounts 
      WHERE  name = 'joongsu'
    ) AS existing_account
SET 
    account_to_be_updated.password = existing_account.password ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking out for?

```
;with CTE as 
(
select password from accounts  where name='joongsu' limit 1
)
update accounts set password= CTE.password
    where id in 
(select accountid from characters where name='Nobless')
```

Comment: I want to change password of ID whose character name is "Noblesse" to ID "joongsu"(not nickname)'s password.

Comment: I'm sorry but what i want is not 'joongsu', but joongsu's password. (select password from accounts where name='joongsu')

Comment: it returns this message "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 password from accounts where name='joongsu') where id in (select accountid fro' at line 1". is it because my mysql version is not latest?

Comment: not sure friend, code which i have given is of SQL Server. Wait will try to get code of mysql.till that time, pls try again bu updated code.

Comment: it returns "You can't specify target table 'accounts' for update in FROM clause". I think the reason is that in subquery, we designated 'acconts' table  which is already used in main query.

Comment: MySQL does not support (writeable) common table expressions (and it would need the statement terminator `;` at the end of the statement not at the beginning.

Comment: Oh! then sorry friend, I can't help you now. Will try out some code on mysql also in coming future.