# You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause in MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I want to change the `status` of a single order by selecting its `requisition_id` where the `status` matches a specific keyword. 
But it keeps showing me this error "You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause"

```
UPDATE order_info
SET status ='Approved' 
WHERE requisition_no IN (SELECT requisition_no FROM order_info WHERE status = 'not approved')
```

What can I do to fix it?

**EDIT- I've included the PHP code as well**

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['requisition_no'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['desig'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['deptt'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['make'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>";
    echo '<form method="post" action="status.php">'; /*Redirects to status.php to change the status (using diff. page because i'm a hopeless kid, who doesnt want to learn new ways of simplifying things)*/
    echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "<br/>";

    if($row['status']=='Approved' || $row['status']=='Under Procurement'){//does nothing
    }
            /*Here, using a submit button*/
    else { echo '<input type="submit" name="status" value="Approve"></td>';
    $_SESSION['rno'] = $row['requisition_no'];}
    echo '</form>';
```

Comment: You are at least missing an equals sign and the right parenthesis `)`.

Comment: and also an "=" is clearly missing.

Comment: Try using a table alias

Comment: I didn't reread my query before posting it, no syntax errors in my actual code though. Still getting the same error.

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few syntax errors probably causing this error. You are missing an equals sign `=` after `status` and the right parenthesis `)` at the end:

```
UPDATE order_info o
SET o.status = 'Approved' 
WHERE o.requisition_no IN (SELECT x.requisition_no FROM (select * from order_info) x WHERE x.status = 'not approved')
```

Also, I think your query can be rewritten like this:

```
UPDATE order_info
SET status = 'Approved' 
WHERE status = 'not approved'
```