# How to Update a Field From The Same Data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, field

```
id     product    main_image
---    ---------- -----------
1      1          0
2      1          0
3      1          0

4      2          0
5      2          0
6      2          0

7      3          0
8      3          0
9      3          0
10     3          0
```

I want to use mysql query to make table field datas (for main_image) like this

```
id     product    main_image
---    ---------- -----------
1      1          1
2      1          0
3      1          0

4      2          1
5      2          0
6      2          0

7      3          1
8      3          0
9      3          0
10     3          0
```

how can I do it? I want to set a main image for products.
I have about 3 millions record, I tried php but its too slow

Comment: Given that the main image is always the first one wonders why you'd need to do this!

Comment: I used Group by to get first image but it is not usefull for me and makes processor tired so I set a main image and use where. And I need a main image for each of 200.000 hotels to show customers at the first view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery to select the smaller id form the table:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET main_image = 1
WHERE id IN
  (SELECT MIN(temp.id)
   FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) AS temp
   GROUP BY temp.product)
```

Comment: Navicat give error "You can't specify target table 'yk_otel_hotel_pictures' for update in FROM clause"
my query
UPDATE yk_otel_hotel_pictures
SET main = '1' WHERE imageURL IN (SELECT imageURL FROM yk_otel_hotel_pictures GROUP BY hotelID)

Comment: Mysql doesn't allow select in subquery on the same table, an easy solution can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause), I made an edit.

Comment: I guess there's a more elegant way of writing this.

Comment: I dublicated table and query worked, thanks every body, thanks Ende

Answer (score 2):

This...

```
UPDATE my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT product
            , MIN(id) min_id 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY product
     ) y 
    ON y.product = x.product 
   AND y.min_id = x.id 
   SET x.main_image = 1;
```

... or just this ...

```
UPDATE my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MIN(id) min_id 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY product
     ) y 
    ON y.min_id = x.id 
   SET x.main_image = 1;
```