# PHP - MySQL - Delete all rows except most recent 3 & This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Tags: php, mysql

I have:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3, 999999999;") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

But it doesn't seem to like it. 
I want to keep the most recent three rows and delete everything else.
Thoughts?

Followup - thanks for the simultaneous jinx!

I tried the code and got this version error:

```
This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

I checked my hosting and I have: MySQL version 5.5.36-cll-lve

I didn't expect this. What version do I need for limits? Is there another way to write this that will work?

Comment: In PHP 5.5 you should be getting warnings that `mysql_query` is a deprecated interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: I'm not a php guy nor a mysql guy. I simply am looking for a faster way to retrieve and store data that I am using with a node.js app that is offsite and pulling from google spreadsheets while doing some complicated oauth authentications. I really just need a simple solution here. If you have a written solution that solves the above problem using PDOs and will not give me a similar error to what's written above, feel free to post it.

Comment: @ShazboticusSShazbot Have you tried Mark's edited answer? Reload if you have not seen the changes made.

Comment: Trying how, missed his edited answer. TY

Comment: You're welcome. It's best placing comments under answers given, in order to let them know that it did not work or other details why. @ShazboticusSShazbot

Comment: Agreed. I put the first one up there because 3 people all responded simultaneously with very similar answers and I lol'd

Comment: I updated my answer and tested it on SQL Fiddle.  I can't believe mySql makes it *this much* of a pain!!  `+1` for the question!

Comment: @ShazboticusSShazbot You'd probably have a better time using the NodeJS MySQL interface if you're already working with it in the first place. PHP for this unnecessary, especially for a simple extract and transform operation.

Comment: I would but the node.js service isn't running on my personal server - it's on heroku which has some latency. My personal server is linux and shared, so node can't be installed on it. It's a bit hacked together, but it's doing some pretty tricky things :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd think your *first* attempt would actually work.  However, the `LIMIT` keyword in the MySql `DELETE` command only supports a *maximum* number of rows, not a range of values to delete.  This is why you see the error you're getting.  Next, you'd think (as I thought) something like this would work:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id NOT IN
   (SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3);
```

However, MySql doesn't seem to support the `IN` or `NOT IN` operators on a `DELETE` statement either.  Next, you'd think something like this would work:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id <
   (SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2,1)
```

However, it seems MySql doesn't support this idea either.  There are some [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause) that say you need to build a temp table, which seems insanely silly!  However, with a bunch of nested selects and alias hackery, I *was* able to get *this* working:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id <
  (select id FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) as t ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2,1);
```

[Working Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1223/1)

It's unbelievable MySql makes it this difficult!  Maybe it's time for a better database, such as PostgreSQL?  It will [just work like you'd expect](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/16c5c/1).

Comment: No problem!  I don't really know mySql very well so I had to mess around with it to get it working.  However, Mark Baker was on the right track and he deserves a `+1` for a nearly working answer.

Comment: Yep. I gave him a +1.

Comment: +1 here too. I particularly liked the way you phrased everything Mike.

Answer (score 7):

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id < ( 
    SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2,1 
)
```

If your version of MySQL complains about subqueries in a delete statement, try

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id < ( 
    SELECT id FROM ( 
        SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2,1 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: OP states (in an edit): *"I tried the code and got this version error:"* - *"This version of MySQL doesn't yet support '`LIMIT` & `IN/ALL/ANY/SOME` subquery'"* - So the OP can't use `LIMIT`? Or, is it just a sub-query issue?

Comment: @Fred-ii- - Uncertain at this point, because I haven't tried it; but certainly the sub-suquery approach works with some deletes that I've tried in the past and MySQL has complained vociferously

Comment: Can you post a working SQL Fiddle?  I still can't get this working, and other SO posts are saying you need to create a temp table.

Comment: Gave it a try, got this - "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: Given your experience Mark, I'm sure your code is kosher.

Comment: *"However, Mark Baker was on the right track and he deserves a +1 for a nearly working answer."* ([`Mike`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26145350/php-mysql-delete-all-rows-except-most-recent-3#comment40984688_26145420)). Indeed. +1 here too.

Comment: My bad for not testing else I'd have spotted the lack of alias, but thanks for the boonie points guys

Answer (score 5):

Filtering the first 3 ID's and delete the rest, you can do it with this query:

```
 DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id NOT IN ( 
  SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3 
 )
```

Comment: Hah!  Basically the exact same answer.

Comment: You guys' timestamps are pretty much all the same. I doubt anyone copied from each other, so it's up to the OP to pick one of the answers. Technically, this answer was given first. `15:53:35` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM mytable
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 3
)
```

I'm not sure what you were trying to do with the second large limit value, but subqueries like this generally make working in SQL much more simple.

Comment: I was looking at previous posts on stackoverflow and one of them had two values, the second being enormous. Thanks for the heads up.