# Update column with Datediff between current and next row

Tags: mysql

The table contains the columns `id`, `timestamp` (eg. 2013-09-23 12:10:53), `activity` and I want to add another column `duration` which would contain the duration of each activity (ie. the difference between the next row time stamp and the current one).

I've tried this query:

```
UPDATE `MyTable` this SET `duration`= 
        (SELECT DATEDIFF(next.`timestamp`, curr.`timestamp`) 
        FROM `MyTable` curr
        JOIN `MyTable` next
        ON next.`id` = curr.`id`+1
        WHERE this.`id` = curr.`id`)
```

And got this error:

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'this' for update in FROM clause
```

How can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, use a `join`:

```
UPDATE MyTable this left join
       MyTable next
       ON next.id = this.id + 1
    SET this.duration = DATEDIFF(next.timestamp, this.timestamp) ;
```

I think the error is self-explanatory.  The usual solution in MySQL is to convert the `update` to use `join`s instead of correlated subqueries.

Comment: This worked best, although it still had some errors in it (I attribute those to the faulty design of the table which isn't mine...). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Some reference for you

[You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

```
UPDATE `MyTable` this SET `duration`= 
    (SELECT DATEDIFF(next.`timestamp`, curr.`timestamp`) 
    FROM (SELECT * from MyTable) curr
    JOIN (SELECT * from MyTable) next
    ON next.`id` = curr.`id`+1
    WHERE this.`id` = curr.`id`);
```

Comment: Tried it and I get the same error. I also removed `this` from the last row and had the same result.