# Error Code 1093 in DELETE statement

Tags: mysql

My query is:-

```
delete from api_data 
WHERE local_id NOT IN( SELECT MAX(local_id) 
                       FROM api_data 
                       GROUP BY local_id);
```

But i am getting error which says:

> You can't specify target table 'api_data' for update in FROM clause.

Any Help?

Comment: Is this really SQL Server or Mysql?

Comment: That error is for mysql,sql server would run the query as it is.

Comment: Definitely MySql with that error number

Comment: possible duplicate of [You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL you can't delete from the same table you are selecting from. But you can use another subquery to cover that

```
delete from api_data
WHERE local_id NOT IN
(
  select * from 
  (
    SELECT MAX(local_id) FROM api_data GROUP BY local_id
  ) tmp
);
```