# MySQL UPDATE with subquery for null

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update the status of all airplanes, using a subquery, to 'OUT' who are currently out and have not returned. My foreign key is PLANE_NUM. I'm trying it like this but I've got an error:

```
UPDATE plane
SET STATUS='OUT'
WHERE PLANE_NUM 
IN (SELECT *
    FROM plane p, flight f
    WHERE p.PLANE_NUM = f.PLANE_NUM
    AND FLIGHT_RETURNDATE IS null);
```

Comment: In your sub query, you are selecting `*` that is all fields. Should you not only be selecting the `PLANE_NUM` that is the corresponding field in your sub query ?

Comment: Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'plane' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem you are facing is because ==> MySQL doesn’t allow referring to a table that’s targeted for update in a FROM clause, which can be frustrating.

This will work for you

```
UPDATE plane
SET STATUS='OUT'
WHERE PLANE_NUM 
IN (SELECT * FROM (select p.PLANE_NUM
    FROM plane p, flight f
    WHERE p.PLANE_NUM = f.PLANE_NUM
    AND FLIGHT_RETURNDATE IS null) as B );
```

Not Optimized. Please refer to links below and optimize as per your requirement

[You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/

Answer (score 2):

A better way of doing is by joining as

```
update plane p
left join flight f
on p.PLANE_NUM = f.PLANE_NUM
SET p.STATUS='OUT'
where f.FLIGHT_RETURNDATE IS null ;
```

Comment: This one doesn't work.This query comes back with planes who don't have a flight as well as the ones whose FLIGHT_RETURNDATE IS null

Comment: Make it `inner join` instead of `left join`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
UPDATE airplane, plane, flight
SET airplane.STATUS='OUT'
WHERE airplane.PLANE_NUM = plane.PLANE_NUM
    AND plane.PLANE_NUM = flight.PLANE_NUM
    AND flight.LIGHT_RETURNDATE IS null
```

Comment: This query throws:
Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'plane' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Try this query:
UPDATE airplane, plane, flight
SET airplane.STATUS='OUT'
WHERE airplane.PLANE_NUM = p.PLANE_NUM
 and p.PLANE_NUM = f.PLANE_NUM
 and LIGHT_RETURNDATE IS null