# How to sum mysql vertically?

Tags: mysql, sql

this is my table

```
ID angka1 angka2
1  80     20
2  10     20
3  10     20
4         0
```

I want to sum angka1 vertically, so the value of angka1 on ID 4 is 100, i already try with code below and works, but i want a simple one, because i have another table (this one is just prototype) with many ID, and this code would very long to write.

```
update halooo set angka1 = (
    select sum(db1+db2+db3) from(
        select
        (select sum(angka1) from halooo where id=1)db1, 
        (select sum(angka1) from halooo where id=2)db2,
        (select sum(angka1) from halooo where id=3)db3
        )total
    )
    where id = 4
```

i try with this one but this code not update my table,

```
update halooo 
set 
angka1=(
    select sum(angka1) from(
        select sum(angka1) from halo) a
    )
where id=4
```

can someone point where is my mistake?

Comment: please more spesific ? just use  'SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name;' goes right here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE halooo SET angka1 = (select SUM(angka1) from (SELECT * FROM halooo) as h WHERE id != 4) WHERE id = 4
```

This should work for your problem if i understood you correctly. It will update column angka1 in row with id 4 with sum of of all rows in column angka1 except row with id 4

Comment: i got an error 
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'halooo' for update in FROM clause

Comment: I update my answer based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause/14302701#14302701

Answer (score 1):

Try;

```
update halooo h,
(
  select sum(COALESCE(angka1, 0)) sum_val
  from halooo
  WHERE id != 4
) x
set h.angka1 = x.sum_val
where h.id = 4;
```

[**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a64eb/1)

Comment: I don't know how mysql handle summing null values, because some DBMS will make the whole sum null, so I would add sum(coalese(angka1,0))

Comment: @Praveen this code works, but the value is increasing, in the first run, the value is 100 (this is what i want), then i run it again and the value become 200, 
thanks though

Comment: @praveen your code is also work, but i can only choose one accepted answer, thanks praveen :)