# Error Code: 1093. Table 'site_html' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update the 'status' column of the table with respective id , but it leads me to error code 1093. 
Below is my SQL Query

```
Update site_html Set status='Update Found' 
Where id = (
            select id 
            from site_html
            where link='http://www.example.com');
```

How can i correct this error? I am new to SQL .

Comment: Your answer is here I guess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause *** or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause/14302701#14302701 *** it appears your query is not match with MySQL standarts. But there are workarounds for this task, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, you can't modify the same table name directly which you use in the SELECT part. So you can do it through table alias.

```
update site_html AS s, (select id  from site_html where link='http://www.example.com') AS t
set status='Update Found' 
where s.id = t.id;
```