# MySql: any way to: UPDATE $tableName SET value=LEAST(value+$change, maxValue)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

As the question-title says i am searching for a way to achieve this in only one sql-call:

```
UPDATE accountEnergy SET value=LEAST(value+$energyChange, maxValue)
```

My solution with two calls:

```
mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE accountEnergy SET value=value+$energyChange WHERE accountId=$accountId");
mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE accountEnergy SET value=maxValue WHERE accountId=$accountId AND value>maxValue");
```

Comment: Can You tell why won't You use first lane u provided ? The one with least?

Comment: because this one-liner will cause a mysql-error

Comment: Does it? What kind of error?

Comment: commented it in the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put this application logic into your application, not into the database (query).

That said, you can solve this with a sub-query:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET yourValue = (
    SELECT LEAST(yourValue + $change, yourMax)
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE yourId = $yourId
)
WHERE yourId = $yourId
```

**Edit:** It appears that MySQL does not allow you to reference the table you are updating also in a sub-query.

A solution to this problem is shown in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14302701/3836229).

Comment: value and maxValue are registered words from sql, putting them into `` solved it
UPDATE w1_account_energy
SET `value` = (
    SELECT LEAST(`value`+10, `maxValue`)
    FROM w1_account_energy
    WHERE accountId = 1
)
WHERE accountId = 1

throws now:
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'w1_account_energy' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Is it solved now or not? Not sure how to read your edited comment.

Comment: Sorry. NOT solved, because of the "can't specify target table for update in FROM clause". maybe i have to use a temp table to get it in one call.

Comment: Have a look at my edit. This seems to be an issue with MySQL that can be solved.

Comment: do it with an "Update with a Self-join" pattern, not a temp-table. Listen to Timo