# simple SUM query for C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I want to ask about simple sum query. In this question, I attached a picture to let you guys see my table. Now, I want to calculate the Januari's Target + Februari's Target = Februari's Target_YtD
What I have got so far is something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZWK8.png)

```
SELECT SUM(Target) as 'Target_YtD' from revenue where Bulan =
"Januari" or Bulan = "Februari"
```

But the query above is only produce the final result of the calculation, and what I want is, I want to put the result in the "revenue" table (which is for Februari's Target_YtD column to be exactly). I really appreciate for those who can help me to figure out. Thank you

Comment: Why did you tag it with C#? I do not see what this question has to do with that language.

Comment: ok sorry for that. but if u got a query to solve my question, please let me know. @Vijay

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that revenue table contains a column named 'Target_YtD' and you want to update this field with sum function for Januari and Februari target values

Use something like that

```
update revenue
set Target_YtD=(select SUM(target) from revenue where Bulan in ('Januari', 'Februari'))
where Bulan='Februari'
```

Comment: appreciate that man, but your query above cannot working on my sql. can u make it a bit clear please?

Answer (score 0):

While Carlos's answer is fully logical and correct, **it won't work**.
More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause).

A quote from the answer in the link:

> That is, if you're doing an UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE on a table, you
>   can't reference that table in an inner query (*you **can** however
>   reference a field from that outer table...*)

This is the updated solution, based on Carlos's answer:

```
update revenue
set Target_YtD=(select SUM(target) from (select * from revenue) as r where r.Bulan in ('Januari', 'Februari'))
where Bulan='Februari'
```