# MySQL query with DELETE where ANY runs too long

Tags: mysql

Here is my query:

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE name = ANY (
SELECT name FROM (
    SELECT sd1.name
    FROM my_table sd1 JOIN my_table sd2
    ON sd2.name > sd1.name
    AND sd2.name & sd1.name = sd1.name
    AND sd1.number >= sd2.number) AS stmp
);
```

name is primary key BIGINT type.

It takes a long time to run even there are not so many rows in my_table.
Any ideas on how to make it run faster.

Comment: What data type do you use for `name`?

Comment: Also I forgot to mention that name is primary key in my_table

Comment: You can edit your question, if you forgot something.

Comment: AND sd2.name & sd1.name = sd1.name - is the & (bitwise AND) really necessary?

Comment: I think correct answer is listed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can pare DELETE with INNER JOIN http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-join/
It still takes a while if JOIN is large.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for sd1.names where exists another record with certain criteria. Then you delete all records with the names found.

Isn't this simply: delete records for which exists another record with certain criteria?

```
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM my_table sd2
    WHERE sd2.name > my_table.name
    AND sd2.name & my_table.name = my_table.name
    AND my_table.number >= sd2.number
  ) dummy
);
```

(**UPDATED:** MySQL cannot access the same table in `UPDATE` or `DELETE` and one must wrap the subquery so the table gets kind of hidden hidden one level deeper. Looks absolutely senseless, but is supposed to solve this issue. Hope it does.)

That's less complicated and therefore maybe faster. Especially since `EXISTS` has to find only one match per main record and can stop there, whereas a join looks for all matches.

Comment: Well, it gives me syntax error:

mysql> 
    DELETE FROM my_table sd1
    WHERE EXISTS
    (
      SELECT *
      FROM my_table sd2
      WHERE sd2.name > sd1.name
      AND sd2.name & sd1.name = sd1.name
      AND sd1.number >= sd2.number
    );
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sd1
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM my_table sd2
  WHERE sd2.name > sd1.name
  ' at line 1

Comment: I had to google this. MySQL doesn't accept a table alias for whatever reason. (They do provide a queer syntax for an alias, but we can easily do without here.) Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I use MySQL aliases all the time. May be something is special in that case. When I run the query as you suggested it errored with message:

ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'my_table' for update in FROM clause

Comment: And here is more on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Comment: Ah another MySQL specialty. If I remember correctly you need to wrap this in a dummy query in MySQL. I've updated again. Hope this works for you.

Comment: DELETE FROM my_table 
    WHERE EXISTS
    (
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT *
      FROM my_table
      ) sd
      WHERE sd.name > my_table.name
      AND sd.name & my_table.name = my_table.name
      AND my_table.number >= sd.number
    );