# MySQL Calculating Running Total Without Variables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to develop a script to update the running total within a table:

```
update transactions set running_total = (select sum(amount) from transactions t2 where t2.sequence_number <= transactions.sequence_number)
```

- running_total = the cumulative sum of the amount column
- sequence_number = the order in which transactions occurred: 1,2,3,4,5...

MySQL is expectedly showing error *You can't specify target table 'transactions' for update in FROM clause*

How can I re-write this script **without** using variables (i.e., by relying only on joins, etc.)

Comment: Try nesting it in another subquery.

Comment: Yes, you cannot do that. You can't refer the table you are updating.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Comment: @Chris - You can check this post on Baron Schwartz's blog too - https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

- Execute the following query:

  `SELECT t.id, t.total, 
  (SELECT SUM(total) FROM transactions WHERE id <= t.id) AS running
  FROM transactions t;`
- Store the output in a temp table (here is the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html))
- Write an update query that will update the records from this table

  `UPDATE transactions t 
  SET running_total = (SELECT running FROM temp WHERE id = t.id);`
- Delete the `temp` table.

For the new `INSERT`s, you can write the logic in your application (or a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger) to calculate running total before a row gets inserted.

Here is the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f5b63/1/0).

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd9bda/1    It can be done with temporary table, but its also possible to accomplish the update in a single statement by making use of inline views (derived tables), in place of the separate steps to create, populate and drop the temporary table.

Comment: @spencer7593 thank you - very helpful & I really appreciate it