# Insert row with cell amount dependent of previous row cell amount

Tags: php, mysql

I have a system balance table "`A`", where the column "amount" is a debit/credit column, like this:

```
id amount balance 
1  100    100 
2  -30    70 
3  40     110
4  -20    90
```

If a new deposit is made of i.e. $50, the new row would have to be inserted as:

```
5  50      140
```

I could achieve this by selecting last balance:

```
SELECT id, balance
FROM A
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

and then inserting new row:

```
INSERT INTO A (amount, balance)
VALUES (50, previous_balance+50)
```

But, is there a way to achieve this with only one query? Would it be efficient on large databases? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do it is :

```
INSERT INTO A(amount,balance) 
VALUES (50, 50 + 
    (SELECT B.balance 
    FROM(SELECT balance FROM A ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS B) 
);
```

Because mysql can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part

Comment: Thank you so much. It works great! And makes sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Just combine your 2 queries:

```
INSERT INTO A (amount, balance)
VALUES (50, (
   SELECT balance
   FROM (SELECT * from A)
   ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
)+50)
```

Comment: I tried that but it is not working, mysql said `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'A' for update in FROM clause`, any thought please?

Comment: Updated, please give it a try, refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Comment: Still not working, still throwing an error. @contremaitre posted the solution. Thank you anyways very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
INSERT INTO A (amount, balance)
  SELECT "50", SUM(balance)
    FROM ( SELECT id+1 as id, 50 balance FROM A
             UNION ALL
           SELECT id, balance FROM A 
             ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2
        ) t
```