# Update Where Column not in Select

Tags: sql, percona

I am trying to update customers where their `website_id` is equal 6 and their email is not duplicate when `website_id` is 3.

I have been able to get all customer where `website_id` is 6 and their email is not duplicate where `website_id` is 3, the SQL statement bellow does that.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM customer_entity
WHERE website_id = 6
AND email NOT IN (SELECT
  email
FROM customer_entity
WHERE website_id = 3);
```

Now when I try to update all customers that have website_id and store_id equal to 3 to 6 where their email is not duplicate in store_id = 3

```
UPDATE customer_entity customers
    SET customers.website_id = 3, customers.store_id = 3 
    WHERE customers.website_id = 6 AND customers.email 
      NOT IN (SELECT email FROM customer_entity WHERE website_id = 3);
```

I get the following error

> You can't specify target table 'customers' for update in FROM clause

How can I achieve what I am trying to do?

EDIT:
I have also tried without the alias and I still get the same error.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Done, I used the percona-server

Comment: updates get a little weird with aliases, might be able to rewrite it without the alias and it should work (at least in MS's flavor of SQL anyways)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for my own question. Many of the answer here use JOINS to one table so for MYSQL, this does not work because you can't update on the same SELECT JOIN.

My solution was to create a temporary table and store all values which had store_id and website_id = 6 and WHERE the email was not duplicate WHERE store_id and website_id = 3.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE customer_temp_table(
   SELECT email FROM customer_entity 
      WHERE 
         website_id = 6 
      AND  
         email NOT IN (SELECT email FROM customer_entity WHERE website_id = 3));
```

Then I update the the customer entity table using results from the temp table.

```
UPDATE customer_entity AS customers SET customers.website_id = 3, customers.store_id = 3
    WHERE customers.email IN (SELECT email FROM customer_temp_table) AND customers.website_id = 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the aliases from the code.
Try this:

```
UPDATE customer_entity 
SET website_id = 3, store_id = 3 
WHERE website_id = 6 AND email 
  NOT IN (SELECT email FROM customer_entity WHERE website_id = 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be using MySQL.  You can do this with a `join`.  I would write this as:

```
update customer_entity ce join
       (SELECT email
        FROM customer_entity
        GROUP BY email
        HAVING SUM(website_id = 6) > 0 AND
               SUM(website_id = 3) = 0
      ) e
      on ce.email = e.email
    set ce.website_id = 3,
        ce.store_id = 3 ;
```

Comment: I get this error Duplicate entry 'secrete-email' for key 'UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_EMAIL_WEBSITE_ID'

Comment: Do you think its because you trying to update stuff with a join of the same table?

Comment: By the way I am using percona not mysql

Answer (score 0):

This is to correct or enhance your update statement

> Update FROM and NOT EXISTS otherwise the basic UPDATE and NOT IN

```
UPDATE customers
    SET website_id = 3
       ,store_id = 3 
    from customer_entity customers
    WHERE website_id = 6 
          AND NOT EXISTS 
            (SELECT 1 
               FROM customer_entity c 
               WHERE c.website_id = 3
               c.email = customers.email
            );
```

UPDATE and NOT IN

```
 UPDATE customer_entity 
        SET website_id = 3
           ,store_id = 3 
        WHERE website_id = 6 
              AND email not in
                (SELECT email
                   FROM customer_entity 
                   WHERE website_id = 3
                );
```

however looking at this statement from your problem

> Now when I try to update all customers that have website_id and
>   store_id equal to 3 to 6 where their email is not duplicate in
>   store_id = 3

this should be your solution : 
UPDATE and NOT EXISTS

```
UPDATE customers

        SET website_id = 6      -- Now when I try to update all customers that have website_id and store_id equal to 3 to 6
           ,store_id = 6 

        from customer_entity customers
        WHERE website_id = 3 and store_id = 3     -- Now when I try to update all customers that have website_id and store_id equal to 3 to 6

              AND NOT EXISTS 
                (SELECT 1 
                   FROM customer_entity c 
                   WHERE c.store_id = customers.store_id        -- where their email is not duplicate in store_id = 3 
                   and c.email = customers.email
                );
```

UPDATE and NOT IN

```
UPDATE customer_entity
        SET website_id = 6      -- Now when I try to update all customers that have website_id and store_id equal to 3 to 6
           ,store_id = 6 

        WHERE website_id = 3 and store_id = 3     -- Now when I try to update all customers that have website_id and store_id equal to 3 to 6

              AND email NOT IN
                (SELECT email 
                   FROM customer_entity c 
                   WHERE store_id = 3       -- where their email is not duplicate in store_id = 3 

                );
```

Comment: Probably coz the for sql-server or mysql. Perhaps what you can do is to format it to new database you're running against

Comment: Not really, for example your last example you are saying "UPDATE customer_entity
        SET website_id = 6, store_id = 6 customer_entity".

Comment: Logically your answers are still incorrect. You can not update tables from table select.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please post here your issue?

Answer (score -1):

If you're doing an **UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE** on a table, you can't reference that table in an inner query (you can however reference a field from that outer table...)

The solution is to replace the instance of myTable in the sub-query with (SELECT * FROM customer_entity), like this

```
SELECT * FROM customer_entity WHERE website_id = 3 as something
```

You can find more info here : [You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)