# Table not updating. You can't specify target table 'nodeassociation' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `abc` and I am trying to update it but I keep getting the following error: `You can't specify target table 'abc' for update in FROM clause`.

Below is my SQL query:

```
UPDATE abc
SET value_1 = xxx
WHERE value_2 = 'ABC' AND id 
IN (Select id FROM abc WHERE value_3 = 'XYZ' AND value_1 = xxx);
```

Could anyone please tell me how I can make this query work?
Many thanks.

Comment: Your error message says nodeassociation, but your code has no such table. Very odd.

Comment: Have you checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14302701/3367442)?

Comment: @SahilPatel Yes, this should be flagged as a duplicate of that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Comment: @underscore_d Reported as a duplicate. Thank you.

Comment: @SahilPatel I _think_, anyway :) I've not used MySQL much. But it's hard to tell with this question because the title and body don't make any sense together as they seem to refer to different tables.

Comment: The table nodeassociation is 'abc'.

Comment: So you should post the actual code you run, not a paraphrased version.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use more than one table in an update statement - like you use subqueries or joins - you have to give the table, which has to be updated an alias (like i called the table myupd_table). 
so you were just missing the `FROM`-part and the alias

```
UPDATE myupd_table
   SET value_1 = xxx
   FROM abc myupd_table
  WHERE myupd_table.value_2 = 'ABC' 
    AND myupd_table.id IN (Select id FROM abc WHERE value_3 = 'XYZ' AND value_1 = xxx);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me:

```
UPDATE abc
SET value_1 = xxx
WHERE value_2 = 'ABC' AND id 
IN (Select t1.id FROM (select * from abc) as t1 
WHERE t1.value_3 = 'XYZ' AND t1.value_1 = xxx);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is a key (probably primary key) of your table, why not using this query instead:

```
UPDATE abc
   SET value_1 = xxx
 WHERE value_2 = 'ABC' 
   AND value_3 = 'XYZ'
   AND value_1 = xxx;
```

otherwise consider using better names for your fields.