# Delete in SQL using derived table

Tags: sql

I have a table named P, which has two columns: id and email. All the id are different and in ascending order, but some id have the same email. I need to delete all the duplicated emails and keep only unique emails with its smallest id. 
The correct query is:

```
DELETE FROM P
WHERE id NOT IN
(
 SELECT minId FROM
 (
  SELECT MIN(id) AS minId, email
  FROM P 
  GROUP BY email
 ) AS Q
)
```

However, it I use the following query, which returns "SyntaxError: near 'AS Q'". Could anybody tell me why. Thanks.

```
DELETE FROM P
WHERE id NOT IN
  (SELECT MIN(id) 
   FROM P 
   GROUP BY email
 ) AS Q
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

remove AS Q not in query is no longer a derived table, this is now a subquery.

```
DELETE FROM P
WHERE id NOT IN
(  SELECT MIN(id) 
   FROM P 
   GROUP BY email
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I removed AS Q and then got another error:   "You can't specify target table 'P' for update in FROM clause". Why don't I have the problem in the first query?

Comment: are you running the first query or the second query? which is the official one?

Comment: the first query won't have a problem because you just aliased the derived table in the subquery but not the subquery...

Comment: Thanks, now I understand why my original second query is incorrect. What's confusing me now is that after removing the AS Q from the second query,  I got an error "You can't specify target table P for updating in FROM clause". As I am also updating P in the FROM clause of my first query, why it does not return an error?

Comment: where is your update statement? you delete statement should be okay

Comment: Finally found that the problem is mySql, a similar post is here: 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Answer (score 0):

You would get the same error if you added `AS P` at the end of the last `)` brace in the first query.

That said you would *probably* get better performance on the match if you used either a JOIN or a `NOT EXISTS` instead of `IN`

```
DELETE FROM P
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(  SELECT 1
   FROM P AS p2
   GROUP BY p2.email
   HAVING MIN(p2.id) = P.id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use an alias for `not in` Operator:

```
DELETE FROM P
WHERE id NOT IN
(  SELECT MIN(id) 
   FROM P 
   GROUP BY email
)
```