# How to combine UPDATE query with subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

In my Mysql database I want to update a field `fup` for all records which I found using this select statement:

```
SELECT ic.hash
FROM incompany as ic, app
WHERE ic.id = app.ic_id;
```

So I created the following combined query:

```
UPDATE incompany
SET fup = 'x' 
WHERE hash IN (SELECT ic.hash
FROM incompany as ic, app
WHERE ic.id = app.ic_id);
```

But this query gives me the following error:

> You can't specify target table 'incompany' for update in FROM clause

Does anybody know how I can make this work? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause#14302701

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want a condition on two columns, so this is a bit tricky.  If I follow the logic correctly:

```
UPDATE incompany ic JOIN
       (SELECT DISTINCT ic.hash
        FROM incompany ic JOIN
             app
             ON ic.id = app.ic_id 
       ) ica
       ON ica.hash = ic.hash
    SET fup = 'x' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a subquery. You might use `INNER JOIN` to set the criteria to link the `incompany` table to the `app` table and to the another alias for `incompany` table.

```
UPDATE incompany I 
INNER JOIN app A ON I.id = A.ic_id
INNER JOIN incompany I2 ON I.hash = I2.hash
SET I.fup = 'x'
```