# On update mysql row (You can't specify target table 'x' for update in FROM clause)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update MySQL row.

my query is

```
update x set available_material_id = null where id not in (select id from x where additional_info = 1);
```

and I am getting this error message: **You can't specify target table 'x' for update in FROM clause**

can anybody help me with this issue?

I am using MySQL version 5.6.38.

i saw this [You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause/14302701) answer but i could not figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `left join`:

```
update x left join
       x xx
       on x.id = xx.id and xx.additional_info = 1
    set available_material_id = null
    where xx.id is null;
```