# JOOQ Update Table with condition of a joined Table

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-update, jooq

I got two Tables like this: Enrollment and Student

```
create table [LECTURE_DB].[dbo].[ENROLLMENT](
[EXAM_PASSED] bit null default ((0)),
[EXAM_TAKEN] bit null default ((0)),
[YEAR] int not null,
[LECTURE_ID] numeric(19) not null,
[STUDENT_ID] numeric(19) not null,
constraint [PK__ENROLLME__FE468F5B2739D489]
  primary key (
    [YEAR], 
    [LECTURE_ID], 
    [STUDENT_ID]
  )
)  

create table [LECTURE_DB].[dbo].[STUDENT](
[ID] numeric(19) identity(1, 1) not null,
[FIRSTNAME] varchar(255) null,
[GENDER] varchar(255) null,
[LASTNAME] varchar(255) null,
[YEAR_OF_BIRTH] int null,
constraint [PK__STUDENT__3214EC273493CFA7]
  primary key ([ID])
)
```

I now try to Update a bunch of Enrollments (the `exam_passed` column) with some `lastname`s, an `Lecture_ID` and a `year`. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54130698/updating-rows-in-jooq-with-joins) I got the idea to use the joined Table.

```
private void updateStudentExamPassed(boolean passed, int lidx, int year, String... studentName) {
    Enrollment enrollment = Enrollment.ENROLLMENT;
    Student student = Student.STUDENT;

    Table<?> joined = enrollment.leftJoin(student).on(enrollment.STUDENT_ID.eq(student.ID));
    ctx.update(joined)        
        .set(enrollment.EXAM_PASSED, passed)
        .where(student.LASTNAME.in(studentName))
        .and(enrollment.YEAR.eq(year))
        .and(enrollment.LECTURE_ID.eq(BigInteger.valueOf(lidx)))
        .execute();       
    }
```

But I get an `DataAccessException` on the `.execute()`

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [update [LECTURE_DB].[dbo].[ENROLLMENT] left outer join [LECTURE_DB].[dbo].[STUDENT] on [LECTURE_DB].[dbo].[ENROLLMENT].[STUDENT_ID] = [LECTURE_DB].[dbo].[STUDENT].[ID] set [LECTURE_DB].[dbo].[ENROLLMENT].[EXAM_PASSED] = ? where ([LECTURE_DB].[dbo].[STUDENT].[LASTNAME] in (?, ?) and [LECTURE_DB].[dbo].[ENROLLMENT].[YEAR] = ? and [LECTURE_DB].[dbo].[ENROLLMENT].[LECTURE_ID] = ?)]; Falsche Syntax in der Nähe des left-Schlüsselworts.
at org.jooq_3.12.1.SQLSERVER2014.debug(Unknown Source)
at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:2717)
at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:755)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:383)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDelegatingQuery.execute(AbstractDelegatingQuery.java:119)
at de.esteam.lecturedb.jooq.tasks.RecordFeaturesTask.updateStudentExamPassed(RecordFeaturesTask.java:42)
at de.esteam.lecturedb.jooq.tasks.RecordFeaturesTask.run(RecordFeaturesTask.java:28)
at de.esteam.lecturedb.jooq.common.LectureDBAnalysis.run(LectureDBAnalysis.java:100)
at de.esteam.lecturedb.jooq.common.LectureDBAnalysis.main(LectureDBAnalysis.java:56)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Falsche Syntax in der Nähe des left-Schlüsselworts.
```

The Documentation did not help me since the condition relies on another table. Is there any hope to get this to work or do I need to get each Enrollment by it self and update it single handedly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using vendor specific syntax

[The question you've linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54130698/521799) is about MySQL. SQL Server does not support this kind of syntax, but you can achieve an equivalent semantics by using the [`UPDATE .. FROM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause. I.e. try this:

```java
ctx.update(enrollment)        
    .set(enrollment.EXAM_PASSED, passed)
    .from(joined)
    .where(student.LASTNAME.in(studentName))
    .and(enrollment.YEAR.eq(year))
    .and(enrollment.LECTURE_ID.eq(BigInteger.valueOf(lidx)))
    .execute();
```

Notice that a `LEFT JOIN` does not make any sense here if you're turning it again into an `INNER JOIN` by having a predicate on the `student` table in your `WHERE` clause.

#### Using standard syntax

I personally prefer using standard SQL syntax whenever it is possible in these cases, as these `UPDATE .. FROM` or `UPDATE .. JOIN` statements can often be replaced by `IN` or `EXISTS` predicates. For example:

```java
ctx.update(enrollment)        
    .set(enrollment.EXAM_PASSED, passed)
    .where(enrollment.STUDENT_ID.in(
        select(student.ID)
        .from(student)
        .and(student.LASTNAME.in(studentName))
    ))
    .and(enrollment.YEAR.eq(year))
    .and(enrollment.LECTURE_ID.eq(BigInteger.valueOf(lidx)))
    .execute();
```