# update query "You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause"

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add new column and wants update its value based on some condition but it does not allow me to do that it says "You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause"

Any Idea, how to do that?

**mysql**

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN step1_pincode VARCHAR(20);

UPDATE test a SET a.step1_pincode = 
(
SELECT CASE WHEN b.RetailerPincode IS NOT NULL 
       THEN RetailerPincode
       ELSE b.StorePartyPincode
END AS step1_pincode1
FROM test b
);
```

Comment: [You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you cannot specify the same table in `SET` clause during `UPDATE`. Moreover, you don't really need a subquery in your case; you can simply use the conditional `CASE .. WHEN` expression directly. Try the following:

```
UPDATE test a 
SET a.step1_pincode = CASE WHEN a.RetailerPincode IS NOT NULL 
                           THEN a.RetailerPincode
                           ELSE a.StorePartyPincode
                      END
```

---

As @TimBiegeleisen rightly suggested in comments, you can actually write this query using [`COALESCE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function, in a concise manner:

```
UPDATE test 
SET step1_pincode = COALESCE(RetailerPincode, StorePartyPincode)
```

Comment: it says "Error Code: 1406
Data too long for column 'step1_pincode' at row 395576"

Comment: @JunedAnsari well this error has nothing to do with the query but your schema definition. Ensure that `step1_pincode` , `RetailerPincode` and `StorePartyPincode` (all these three columns have similar datatype and size defined). Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE test` and add the details of that to the question.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya A more concise version: `SET a.step1_pincode = COALESCE(a.RetailerPincode, a.StorePartyPincode)`