# UPDATE SQL Table with random unique numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, random

Hi I have a trouble with SQL UPDATE. I want to insert random unique number from 0-2 to column draft in table draft (where column lobby is 1).

I have this, but it ends with error: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'draft' for update in FROM clause

```
UPDATE draft 
SET draft = (
  SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 3) AS random_num 
  WHERE "random_num" NOT IN (
    SELECT draft FROM draft
  )
) 
WHERE lobby = 1
```

RAND range will be generated dynamic on app level so the result should be like this: 3 records = unique random 0-2, 9 records = unique numbers from 0-8 etc.

Start

```
ID DRAFT LOBBY
1  null  1
2  null  1
3  null  1
```

Result

```
ID DRAFT LOBBY
1  1     1
2  2     1
3  0     1
```

Any help please?

### Edit

I updated the query to this:

```
UPDATE draft 
SET draft = (
  SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 3) AS random_num 
  WHERE "random_num" NOT IN (SELECT draft FROM (SELECT * FROM draft) AS temp)
) 
WHERE lobby = 1
```

No syntax error apears, but doesnt change any row, dont know why.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Please provide sample data and desired results.  Three random numbers doesn't give you much choice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Comment: Is the problem you are trying to solve persisting to the db a random sort order or something like that? Sounds like you want to do it the other way around, i.e. initialise all records to null, `update draft set draft = THENUMBER where draft IS NOT NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` - in a loop

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
update draft d cross join
       (select n.*
        from (select 0 as n union all select 1 as n union all select 2) n
        where n.n not in (select d2.draft from draft d2)
        order by rand()
        limit 1
       ) n
    set d.random_number = n.n
    where d.lobby = 1
    limit 1;
```

Note the `limit 1`.  This allows you to update one row at a time.  If multiple rows meet the condition, then you should repeat the `update` with appropriate filtering criteria.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you probably think that this:

```
WHERE "random_num" NOT IN...
```

compares the column `random_num` against the values after IN, but this is not the case.
Why? Because a computed column like `random_num` cannot be used in the WHERE clause
 
What it is doing is comparing the string `"random_num"` which is converted to `0` in order to perform the comparison.
This will work if the `id`s are (like your sample data) 3 consecutive integers:

```
update draft d cross join (
  select group_concat(t.x order by rand() separator '') col
  from (select 0 x union all select 1 union all select 2) t
) r
set d.draft = substr(r.col, d.id % 3 + 1, 1)
where d.lobby = 1;
```

The column `draft` will be updated with 3 unique random integers in the range `0-2`.
 
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/UYmYmyfcJqi2Nepz7EiEN/1).