# Display the MAX date for each record in a WHERE IN clause SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Using MySQL, I have the following table called `subscriptions` shown below

```
name,   renewal_date,    national_id
---------------------------------------
ted,     1/2/2010,        A1111R
ben,     1/3/2010,        A145E1
bob,      8/4/2009,       A11C11
kate,     2/2/2010,       A111E1
ted,     12/2/2011,       A1111R
bob,     12/2/2014,       A11C11
ben,     12/2/2016,       A145E1

etc..
```

The table has about 150000 records. Each person can have multiple subscriptions. I want to display the maximum/latest `renewal_date` for each record in a list given to me for querying. Here is my sql statement:

```
select d.name, d.renewal_date, d.national_id
from subscriptions d
where renewal_date= (select max(d1.renewal_date) 
                     from subscriptions d1 
                     where d1.national_id = d.national_id IN ('A1111R','A11C11', 'A145E1' ....));
```

When I run the query in phpmyadmin, it does not seem to end executing, even when the records in the `IN` clause are few.

Which is the best way to do it? I should also say am not an SQL expert yet :-) Thanks in advance

Comment: For MySQL it would be good to know the version you are using. There have been important changes made lately. Some things are much easier to achieve in MySQL 8 than in previous versions.

Comment: Can there be two different national_id for the same name in the table? If so, do you want one result row for the name or one result row per name and national_id?

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenKettner. The MySQL version is 5.7.25. And no, there can't be two different national_ids for the same name in the table.

Comment: Then it's time you fix your database design. One table for the persons with their national ID, one for the subscriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the names and national ids don't change for a given person, you can just use aggregation:

```
select d.name, max(d.renewal_date), d.national_id
from subscriptions d
where d.national_id in ( . . . )
group by d.name, d.national_id;
```

If you want all columns on the row, the most efficient method is typically a correlated subquery with the right index:

```
select s.*
from subscriptions s
where s.national_id in ( . . . ) and
      s.renewal_date = (select max(s2.renewal_date)
                        from subscriptions s2
                        where s2.national_id = s.nation_id
                       );
```

The right index is `(national_id, renewal_date)`.  Actually, this is probably faster than the `group by` query as well under many circumstances.

Comment: Thank you so much @gordon-linoff for the great answer and the quick response. The second example worked for me. Finally, If I wanted to delete those renewal_dates I have displayed, how would I convert from `select` to `delete`? Something like `delete s.renewal_date from...`?

Comment: @adamvanbart: In order to delete those rows, simply change `select s.*`to `delete`. Or do you want to update the rows and only delete (i.e. make null) their date?

Comment: Thanks @gordonlinoff. I don't want to delete the entire row, but only the `renewal_date`

Comment: Then change `select s.* from subscriptions s` to `update subscriptions s set renewal_date = null`.

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenKettner. However MySQL throws an error: `#1093 - You can't specify target table 's' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: Ah, that's an odd MySQL flaw with a table being specified twice in an update statement. You can circumvent this by replacing `from subscriptions s2` by `from (select * from subscriptions) s2`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Answer (score 0):

You want the maximum renewal_date per name. If that's it, then all you need to do is aggregate:

```
select name, max(renewal_date)
from subscriptions
group by name
order by name;
```

I don't know, how the national_id comes into Play. Can a person's national_id really change from one subsription to another? Or is this a defect in your database design?

You may want this:

```
select name, national_id, max(renewal_date)
from subscriptions
group by name, national_id
order by name, national_id;
```

or this:

```
select name, max(renewal_date), any_value(national_id)
from subscriptions
group by name
order by name;
```

or this:

```
select *
from subscriptions
where (name, renewal_date) in
(
  select name, max(renewal_date)
  from subscriptions
  group by name
)
order by name;
```