# Data truncation: Truncated incorrect date value error

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm using MySQL version: 5.7.22

So I'm trying to have a table that contains a date column from string. The text field contains data in following DateTime format `"d/m/YYYY h:m:s"` format. e.g. `"14/11/2018 20:10:04 +00:00"`.

I want to alter the table with a new column that is of the following format `'%Y-%m-%d'`. I get a

> Data truncation: Truncated incorrect date value error

when I try to update the table. But I get the result when I just use a select statement to convert from string to date.

```
UPDATE BIG_DATA SET BIG_DATA.RealDate = ( SELECT x.d
                                          From (SELECT (DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(BIG_DATA.Date , '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')) as d
                                          FROM BIG_DATA) as x);
```

Any help would be grateful!

Comment: Rather than having multiple columns for different formats of the same date, have you considered a single [`datetime`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) column which you [format as needed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)?

Comment: I am creating a new column just because I will be needing the original column in the future.

Comment: Could that new column be a `datetime` to avoid having to do this again in the future?

Comment: Is there a reason you have nested queries 3 deep? Also, what is the datatype for Realdate? If its a date then you dont need to convert your STR_TO_DATE back to a string again.

Comment: Yeah `datetime` format works for me.

Comment: @TomC RealDate is in Date format. The reason it is nested because it gave me an error 1093, so I referred this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Comment: Is the current `Date` column a varchar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting an error is that the warning for an incorrect date value (one that produces a value with zeros in it) that is produced by `STR_TO_DATE` on a `SELECT` is promoted to an error when you attempt to do an `UPDATE`. For example, if you do

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('14/11/2018 20:10:04 +00:00', '%d/%m/%Y');
SHOW WARNINGS
```

Your output will be:

```
2018-11-14
Warning     1292    Truncated incorrect date value: '14/11/2018 20:10:04 +00:00'
```

You can work around this by *only* supplying the date part (the leftmost 10 characters) of the string to `STR_TO_DATE`:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(LEFT('14/11/2018 20:10:04 +00:00', 10), '%d/%m/%Y');
SHOW WARNINGS
```

Output is simply `2018-11-14`

This then allows you to create your other column and `UPDATE` it from the `date` column:

```
ALTER TABLE big_data ADD
realdate DATE;
UPDATE big_data
SET realdate = STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(date, 10), '%d/%m/%Y');
SELECT * FROM big_data
```

Another possibility you might want to consider is using a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html):

```
ALTER TABLE big_data ADD
realdate DATE AS (STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y'));
SELECT * FROM big_data
```

In both cases the output is

```
date                        realdate
14/11/2018 20:10:04 +00:00  2018-11-14
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c50c8210e112ac2919439767bf2cce05)