# Update deleted field on a table where there are duplicates - SQL Error (1093): You can't specify target table

Tags: mysql

I would like to mark rows as deleted when there are duplicate stock codes. This is my current query:

```
UPDATE stock s1
SET s1.deleted_at = now()
WHERE s1.product_id != (
    SELECT MIN(s2.product_id)
    FROM stock s2
    WHERE s2.stock_code = s1.stock_code
)
```

Error returned is:

> SQL Error (1093): You can't specify target table 's' for update in
>   FROM clause

I have tried wrapping it within another sub query but unable to get it working

Comment: Use multiple-table UPDATE syntax (move subquery from WHERE to FROM in JOIN form). And replace `!=` condition with `<` - it will simplify the task avoiding GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql doesn't like that you reference the table that you want to upodate in the set.
What you can do is this.

```
UPDATE stock s1
SET s1.deleted_at = now()
WHERE s1.product_id != (
    SELECT MIN(s2.product_id)
    FROM (SELECT product_id, stock_code FROM stock) s2
    WHERE s2.stock_code = s1.stock_code
)
```

[More to that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Comment: Thanks that's working for me. I editted your answer to include stock_code in the sub query.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around this issue with a multi-table `UPDATE` using a self-JOIN:

```
UPDATE stock s1
JOIN stock s2 ON s2.product_id < s1.product_id AND s2.stock_code = s1.stock_code
SET s1.deleted_at = NOW()
```