# Django query to remove older values grouped by id?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Im trying to remove records from a table that have a duplicate value by their oldest timestamp(s), grouping by ID, so the results would be unique values per ID with the newest unique values per ID/timestamp kept, hopefully the below samples will make sense.

sample data:

```
id     value    timestamp
10     10       9/4/20 17:00
11     17       9/4/20 17:00
21     50       9/4/20 17:00
10     10       9/4/20 16:00
10     10       9/4/20 15:00
10     11       9/4/20 14:00
11     41       9/4/20 16:00
11     41       9/4/20 15:00
21     50       9/4/20 16:00
```

so id like to remove any values that have a dupliate value with the same id, keeping the newest timestamps, so the above data would become:

```
id     value    timestamp
10     10       9/4/20 17:00
11     17       9/4/20 17:00
21     50       9/4/20 17:00
10     11       9/4/20 14:00
11     41       9/4/20 16:00
```

EDIT:

query is just

```
SampleData.objects.all()
```

Comment: Can you show how did you obtain the first table? (probably the ORM query)

Comment: ive added it, the first table is just a query on the full table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be using `Subquery` expressions as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions).

Suppose your SampleData model looks like this:

```
class SampleData(models.Model):

    id2 = models.IntegerField()
    value = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

(I replaced id by id2 to avoid conflicts with the model id).

Then you could delete your duplicates like this:

```
newest = SampleData.objects.filter(id2=OuterRef('id2'), value=OuterRef('value')).order_by('-timestamp')
SampleData.objects.annotate(newest_id=Subquery(newest.values('pk')[:1])).exclude(pk=F('newest_id')).delete()
```

Edit:

It seems as if MySQL has some issues handling deletions and subqueries, as documented in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause/14302701#14302701) SO post.

In this case a 2 step approach should help: First getting the ids of the objects to delete and then deleting them:

```
 newest = SampleData.objects.filter(id2=OuterRef('id2'), value=OuterRef('value')).order_by('-timestamp')
 ids2delete = list(SampleData.objects.annotate(newest_id=Subquery(newest.values('pk')[:1])).exclude(pk=F('newest_id')).values_list('pk', flat=True))
 SampleData.objects.filter(pk__in=ids2delete).delete()
```

Comment: when I try run the delete command I get django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1093, "You can't specify target table 'monitoring_data' for update in FROM clause")

Comment: What Database are you using?

Comment: hi, using mysql

Comment: Sorry, there I missed converting the ```values_list``` into a native python ```list```. See my update of the second approach. Tested it with MySQL and this should not throw that error