# How to make a SELECT MAX(id) inside UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm starting in Mysql and I'm trying to find a way to select the maximum id inside update. This is what I tried but it doesn't work.

```
UPDATE `chatMessages` 
SET send = 'true' 
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `chatMessages`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.

```
UPDATE `chatMessages` 
SET send = 'true' 
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Great, I don't know why the way I did it didn't work, as much as it seems to be right, thanks

Comment: MySQL doesn't allow you to use a subquery in the same table in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause