# Using a CTE to delete Nulls Shows Error [1292] [22001]: Data Truncation: Truncated Incorrect DECIMAL

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression, sql-delete, dbeaver

I am trying to find a way to delete all rows with NULL values in a table.  On this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70903217/error-code-1093-you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause), I saw that you can't specify a target table from updates in the FROM clause.  Therefore, I tried building a CTE to perform a bulk delete of all rows with NULL values in a table.  This is the table structure:
[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW2YA.png)

I created the following code:

```
WITH cte_delete AS
(
    SELECT ride_id
    FROM bikes.work
    WHERE ride_id IS NULL OR ride_id = ''
        UNION ALL
    SELECT ride_id
    FROM bikes.work
    WHERE bike_type IS NULL OR bike_type = ''
        UNION ALL    
    SELECT ride_id
    FROM bikes.work
    WHERE started_at IS NULL OR started_at = ''
        UNION ALL
    SELECT ride_id
    FROM bikes.work
    WHERE ended_at IS NULL OR ended_at = ''
        UNION ALL
    SELECT ride_id
    FROM bikes.work
    WHERE start_sta_name IS NULL OR start_sta_name = ''
        UNION ALL
    SELECT ride_id
    FROM bikes.work
    WHERE start_sta_id IS NULL OR start_sta_id = ''
        UNION ALL
    SELECT ride_id
    FROM bikes.work
    WHERE end_sta_name IS NULL OR end_sta_name = ''
        UNION ALL
    SELECT ride_id
    FROM bikes.work
    WHERE end_sta_id IS NULL OR end_sta_id = ''
        UNION ALL
    SELECT ride_id
    FROM bikes.work
    WHERE start_lat IS NULL OR start_lat = ''
        UNION ALL
    SELECT ride_id
    FROM bikes.work
    WHERE start_lng IS NULL OR start_lng = ''
        UNION ALL
    SELECT ride_id
    FROM bikes.work
    WHERE end_lat IS NULL OR end_lat = ''
        UNION ALL
    SELECT ride_id
    FROM bikes.work
    WHERE end_lng IS NULL OR end_lng = ''   
        UNION ALL
    SELECT ride_id
    FROM bikes.work
    WHERE user_type IS NULL OR user_type = '' 
)
DELETE FROM bikes.WORK 
WHERE ride_id = (SELECT ride_id FROM cte_delete);
```

This gave me the error:

> SQL Error [1292] [22001]: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DECIMAL
> value: ''.

I thought my query just pulled the ride_ids, so I don't know why the latitude and longitude values are acting up.  I used DECIMAL(12,10) because I read that it is best for migrating data.  Does anyone have any tips for completing the bulk delete of any rows with NULL values?  Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use a direct delete without cte? in any case why are you checking for empty string if the field is decimal? and by the way, all fields are nullable?

Comment: This seems pretty over-complicated.  But if your longitude and latitude columns are decimals,  `start_lat = ''` is not going to work.

Comment: Hi guys. This is for a work portfolio. I am trying to show my coding skills so I can change careers into data analytics. That's why I thought creating a CTE and showing a more elegant procedure would be best.

Comment: This table does not have any particular restrictions as far as primary or secondary keys. In my analysis, i will delete the ride_ids to prevent customer identification.

Comment: @KennySmith not always the more elegant is the more pleasant, for coding sometimes is better go to the sure, quick, performant or even more, "out of the box"

Comment: @LeandroBardelli I am experiencing this now.  If I had done what you had suggested, it would have been much easier to identify the error.  I will try to apply this advice for the rest of the project.  Thank you!

Comment: @KennySmith glad to help! if my question helps you, dont forget vote it up and/or mark it as correct! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't check for empty string if the field is not VARCHAR. Also only check for `NULL` if the field is nullable.

```
DELETE FROM bikes.WORK 
     WHERE ride_id IS NULL OR ride_id = ''
        OR bike_type IS NULL OR bike_type = ''
        OR started_at IS NULL OR started_at = ''
        OR ended_at IS NULL OR ended_at = ''
        OR start_sta_name IS NULL OR start_sta_name = ''
        OR start_sta_id IS NULL OR start_sta_id = ''
        OR end_sta_name IS NULL OR end_sta_name = ''
        OR end_sta_id IS NULL OR end_sta_id = ''
        OR start_lat IS NULL 
        OR start_lng IS NULL
        OR end_lat IS NULL 
        OR end_lng IS NULL 
        OR user_type IS NULL OR user_type = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to compare values with DECIMAL type to a STRING, e.g. `start_lat = ''` which is not possible.